# Certificado SSL incorrecto ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, certificado-ssl

Muy buenas a todos vieras que estaba instalando 2 certificados de seguridad dominio1 y dominio2 cuando instale el certificado de dominio1 todo esta bien pero cuando instale el certificado del dominio2 me aparece " **ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**" veo cual es el error y dice que el certificado es para el dominio1 y no el dominio2.

Voy a la configuración del apache y veo que las direcciones estan apuntando a los certificados que corresponden. Reinicio el apache y no se soluciona el problema.

**Ademas cuando acepto que la pagina no es segura y entro me muestra el contenido del dominio1 y no el contenido del dominio2**

Mi pregunta es la siguiente

**¿Porque apache esta viendo el certificado incorrecto para el dominio2?**

**Nota 1:** Ya revise que cada certificado este emitido para el dominio1 y dominio2

**Nota 2:** revise el contenido de los certificados y los compare con los correos que descargue y todo esta bien.

Configuración en el apache
Esta es la configuración para dominio2 y dominio1 es igual pero esa funciona bien.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio2/web/
ServerName dominio2

<Directory /var/www/dominio2>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>



SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/www/dominio2/ssl/ssl_certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/dominio2/ssl/dominio2.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /var/www/dominio2/ssl/dominio2.ca-bundle

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Te fijaste que no sea el mismo archivo con diferente nombre. Si no es eso agrega a la pregunta la configuración de los servidores.

Comment: Gracias por leer esto. Y revise que los contenidos sean los que descargue donde los compre.

Comment: Lo que intuyo es que estás ingresando una url que te llava a la maquina correcta pero el dominio que está en la url no matchea con ninguno de los servername del archivo de virtual hosts y te está derivando al virtualhost default. Como el puerto es 443 asegurate de poner el https en la url. Es decir que ingresando la que pensas es la url de dominio2 te está llevando a dominio1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que me comentas, tu servidor esta tomando 1 configuracion para ambos dominios. Tienes que especificar un ServerName para cada uno de los dominios. Te comparto un ejemplo con una nueva instalacion de Apache:

Dejando la configuracion de /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf sin modificaciones, cree 2 configuraciones de 2 vhosts en /etc/httpd/conf.d/ , uno para dominio1 y otro para dominio2

```
[root@vm2 conf.d]# ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  122 Aug 24 23:29 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root   92 Aug 24 22:18 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2926 Jul 29 12:18 autoindex.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   86 Aug 24 23:29 domain1.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   97 Aug 24 23:23 domain2.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  366 Jul 29 12:19 README
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1252 Jul 29 10:15 userdir.conf
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  824 Jul 29 10:15 welcome.conf
```

En esta configuracion, inclui el ServerName de ambos dominios:

```
[root@vm2 conf.d]# cat domain1.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

[root@vm2 conf.d]# cat domain2.conf
<Virtualhost *:80>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain2
        ServerName domain2.com
</Virtualhost>
```

Despues de reiniciar Apache, el servidor web resuelve de manera correcta ambos dominios:

```
[root@vm1 ~]# curl domain1.com
Hello There. This is the main domain

[root@vm1 ~]# curl domain2.com
This is domain 2
```